# SSRS show text box value only in first row of every new page

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a `SSRS` report, I have grouped Parent Group by Area and then Child Group by Code and have deleted the Columns Only for both the groups. 
Also I have set Area Parent Group to have page break between each instance of group.

I want the Code to be available in each row. Along with Area Name only at first row of each page.

**Page 1:**

```
╔═════════════╤════════╤════════╗
║ Area & Code │ Street │ Orders ║
╠═════════════╪════════╪════════╣
║ 12 - US     │ AZ     │ 2      ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 13          │ AQ     │ 1      ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 14          │ AW     │ 5      ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 17          │ AE     │ 6      ║
╚═════════════╧════════╧════════╝
```

**Page 2:**

```
╔═════════════╤════════╤════════╗
║ Area & Code │ Street │ Orders ║
╠═════════════╪════════╪════════╣  // As you can see here US is missing.                                          
║ 18          │ AG     │ 10     ║  // I want US to appear here like 18 - US
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 19          │ BQ     │ 13     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 21          │ CW     │ 53     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 22          │ DE     │ 72     ║
╚═════════════╧════════╧════════╝
```

**Page 3:**

```
╔═════════════╤════════╤════════╗
║ Area & Code │ Street │ Orders ║
╠═════════════╪════════╪════════╣
║ 18 - AU     │ AG     │ 10     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 19          │ BQ     │ 13     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 21          │ CW     │ 53     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 22          │ DE     │ 72     ║
╚═════════════╧════════╧════════╝
```

Expected Result in Page 2: US Should come in with code in First row.

```
╔═════════════╤════════╤════════╗
║ Area & Code │ Street │ Orders ║
╠═════════════╪════════╪════════╣
║ 23 - US     │ AG     │ 10     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 24          │ BQ     │ 13     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 25          │ CW     │ 53     ║
╟─────────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 26          │ DE     │ 72     ║
╚═════════════╧════════╧════════╝
```

Below expression is in Area & Code text box  , But it only shows new area at the start of page.

```
=Fields!AreaCode.Value + IIF(Previous(Fields!AreaName.Value)=Fields!AreaName.Value,"",

 IIF(Fields!AreaName.Value="","", "- "+ Fields!AreaName.Value))
```

How can i fix this , Is there a way to determine whether the current page and write below expression ?

```
=Fields!AreaCode.Value + if current page is new page then show the Area Name in first row 
of page else hide it ?
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/8/20/repeating-column-headers-on-every-page-in-ssrs-doesnt-work-o.html

Comment: @MiguelH , Thanks, I quickly saw the article , it is grouping different value, But as you can see in my Area Group, when the group rows fills next page and in spite US being same value it should be see in first row of every page.

Comment: DO page breaks occur only when the Area changes or can an Area span across pages?

Comment: @AlanSchofield , Both, I mean When new Area changes then it will show in first row and when same area has more rows in next page then show that area name as well in first row of second page.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

A solution may be to create a new column in your dataset to use a main "mainGroup". The expression should be something like `=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/4)`  (number 4 if you want 4 rows per pages)

Then, in the cell, use an expression like :

`=IIF(RowNumber("mainGroup")=1, Fields!AreaCode.Value + "- "+ Fields!AreaName.Value, Fields!AreaName.Value)`

To finish, use "mainGroup" to page break your SSRS.

I dindn't try but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, for the Idea, Should i create new column in `Tablix` or in `dataset` ? and what if the rows are not limited per page ?

Comment: Also I don't have space to add new column in `Tablix`